# Firebase problem documentSnapChot.forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array which is called "TeamArray" and I send data into it via my DB on firebase

```
firestore()
            .collection("Teams")
            .where("City", "==", data.structured_formatting.main_text)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                console.log("no documents found");
              } else {
                querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                  let Teams = doc._data;
                  updateTeamArray([Teams]);
                  console.log(TeamArray);
                });
              }
```

And when I trigger the function I ask firestore to give me only the data that match with the filter and there are several of them. I just want to receive an array with all the data in it and instead, the "doc._data" is giving me the data one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You try this piece of code. Hopefully your query will be resolved. I have also search data from Firebase like this.

```
         firestore()
        .collection("Teams")
        .where("City", "==", data.structured_formatting.main_text)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            console.log("no documents found");
          } else {
            querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
              let Teams = doc._data;
              TeamArray.push(doc._data())
              console.log(TeamArray);
            });
          }
```